# Save array of data from one check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have view that created from сontributed API

```
=form_tag add_group_vk_vk_entries_path, method: :put do
  -length_of_array = @vk_groups['message']['vk'].length
    .row-fluid
      -@vk_groups['message']['vk'][1..length_of_array].each do|item| 
        .span4
          p= check_box_tag "vk_groups[]", item['gid']
          p=item['name']
          p=image_tag item['photo'], :size => "100x100",:class => "img-circle"
= submit_tag "ok"
```

I want to sent the data from this api to my controller by check_box_tag. I want to send not only item['gid'] i want to sent to my controller all data that i checked through one check_box_tag  but i don't anderstand how.

In my controller

```
def add_group_vk
    params[:vk_groups].each do |item|
      if VkEntry.not_exists?(item) == true
        VkEntry.create!(
           :git => item
          )
      end
    end
    redirect_to vk_entries_url
  end
```

i want something like this

```
def add_group_vk
    params[:vk_groups].each do |item|
      if VkEntry.not_exists?(item) == true
        VkEntry.create!(
           :git => item[:gid],
           :name=> item[:name],
           :ser=> item[:ser],
           :photo=> item[:photo]
          )
      end
    end
    redirect_to vk_entries_url
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  I'm assuming that your above generates the check boxes with names like:

```
vk_groups[100], vk_groups[101],...
```

All you can really extract is a list of id's, they're in the the hash key,  the value is not important.

params[:vk_groups] will yield a hash, iterate over the hash like so

```
def add_group_vk
  params[:vk_groups].each do |key,val|
  if VkEntry.not_exists?(key) == true
    VkEntry.create!(
       :git => key,
       :name=> item[:name],
       :ser=> item[:ser],
       :photo=> item[:photo]
      )
  end
end
redirect_to vk_entries_url
```

end

Answer (score 0):

As a result i done:

```
def add_group_vk
    params[:vk_groups].each do |key,val|  

      item = eval val

      if VkEntry.not_exists?(key) == true

        VkEntry.create!(
            :gid          => key,
            :name         => item['name'],
            :screen_name  => item['screen_name'],
            :is_closed    => item['is_closed'],
            :is_admin     => item['is_admin'],
            :is_member    => item['is_member'],
            :type_vk      => item['type_vk'],
            :photo        => item['photo'],
            :photo_medium => item['photo_medium'],
            :photo_big    => item['photo_big']
          )
      end
      end
     redirect_to vk_entries_url
  end
```

In view

```
p= check_box_tag "vk_groups[#{item['gid']}]", item
```